# Swift: 'IN' query alternative using NSPredicate for fetching records from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

**In iCloud**, I want to search in Item's table, where I have userId column in swift but I didn't know how

**Table: User**

```
UserId {String type}
UserName {String type}
```

**Table: Item**

```
ItemId {String type}
ItemName {String type}
UserId {String type}
```

I need NSPredicate alternative to this query

```
Select * from item where userId in (2,3,4)
```

Also, is there any way so I can fire sql query directly in iCloud?

---

Is this is the correct way of doing above in Swift?

```
var orList = [NSPredicate]()
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "userId = %i", 2))
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "userId = %i", 3))       
orList.append(NSPredicate(format: "userId = %i", 4))
```

### Or is there any way to pass array of [2, 3, 4]

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
let usrIds:[Int] = [1,2,3];
let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId IN %@", usrIds);
```

ref.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html